# Options for video development

Tags: i2c, spi, embedded, camera, soc

What are my options for video development? I am talking buying a development board, then translate that to custom pcbs and hardware.
With the rise of smart phones we have seen a plethora of hardware that can do video capure, and/or output to dispaly.

But there is not much documentation available on building your own systems.

The only options i know is the DaVinci SoC with the leopardboard for testing. But since it is a BGA package, it has problems to get your custom pcb.

I also know of the MCUCam5 which uses LPC4330.

Any experienced person in this domain to guide my through my development?
I wan to create an application that will record video from common cell phone cameras (through SPI or I2C) to SD card and dispaly on a colour display at the same time.

Comment: Your cell phone camera can already record video to an SD card while simultaneously displaying it on a color screen; can you not just write an app to leverage this existing hardware to your needs? If you really want to roll your own hardware, the OpenMV project is a good place to start.

Comment: Common cell cameras use an interface called [MIPI CSI](http://mipi.org/specifications/camera-interface) (Camera Serial Interface) to transfer the video data. The I2C or SPI bus is just for control. A [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) has a CSI interface that makes it easy to experiment with apps.

Comment: On a derivative question, does anyone know how to search the market for processors/SoCs that support CSI and have embedded linux option?

Comment: Yes, but it is unlikely to come in other than legless (BGA) package. Just use the Raspberry Pi or similar board. Anecdotally, it is almost nothing more than typical connection for the SoC in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Pixy cam by charmed labs? It is an opensource system on a small footprint with arduino compatability so you can hit the ground running.

Great processing power too for image tracking and what not.

http://charmedlabs.com/default/pixy-cmucam5/

****Edit

I2C is definitely too slow to record quality video. SPI may be as well. Honestly if you're going for hacker, I would shoot the pixy. If you want professional grade experience use the DaVinci dev platform.

Comment: yeah, i mentioned that in my original post, it uses the LPC4330

Comment: The LPC4330 is an NXP processor. I'm not sure how common place they are for video processors but they're not something I know anyone committing heavy experience or time learning.

The main processors I saw at TechCON for ARM processors was TI, Freescale, and Renesas. I guess the main question is, what is your end game with this project?

Also, the oCam by AmeriDroid is a decent platform to play with... 
http://ameridroid.com/products/ocam-5mp-usb30-camera

Comment: Just standard get camera input, store to SD card, output on display. Maybe add wifi or bluettoth interface. But, i want to move from development board to my own circuit. That is the catch. Otherwise it would be easily feasible. So i don't know the options of processors, SoCs.. Thanks for the OCam link!